# How to get the sim card's voicemail number on Android?

Tags: android, voicemail

Is it possible to get the SIM card voicemail number on Android? Looks like it's possible to get via the transfert menu or USSD code, but I can't get it.

I dont want to have the number the user should type to be able to listen to its message, but the number where is transferred an incoming call that cannot reach the user… Meaning the carrier voicemail infrastructure message.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
return tel.getVoiceMailNumber();
```

> public String getVoiceMailNumber()
>
> Returns the voice mail number. Return null if it is unavailable.
>
> Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE

[More here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)